# Is the cosine method inaccurate in Java?

Tags: java

I am posting this question because I tried searching for similar questions in Stack Overflow but couldn't find one (If there is one, please provide me wit the link).

According to basic trigonometry, the cosine of `90 degrees` is `0`. However, it seems like this is not the case in Java (Is this also true for sine and other trigonometric functions?). I'm really confused about this and I am hoping someone could provide me with an easy-to-understand explanation. Thank you.

```
public static void main ( String args [] ) {
    double radians = Math.toRadians ( 90 );
    System.out.println ( Math.cos ( radians ) );
}
```

I should be getting `0`, but what I get when I run this code is `6.123233995736766E-17`.

Comment: 6.1E-17 is really close to 0. This is because of floating point calculations which are not precise.

Comment: Floating point numbers tend to not be entirely accurate for irrational numbers.  That answer is probably nearly exact for the rounded pi/2 created by toRadians().  0.00000000000000006 is really close to 0.

You'll probably need a different library for exact answers.

Comment: double radians = Math.toRadians ( 90 );
    System.out.println ( Math.round(Math.cos ( radians ) ));

Comment: `Math.toRadians ( 90 )` does not convert 90 degrees to pi/2 radians exactly.  That would take infinite precision.  Instead a value _nearest_ to pi/2 is saved in `radians`.  It is this value given to `cos()`. The cosine of that nearest-to-pi/2 value is `6.123...E-17`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

6.123233995736766E-17 is probably about as close as you can get to 0 with a double...

See [Comparing a double against zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194917/comparing-a-double-against-zero) for more info

Comment: Well, you can get 0 with a double. That's even closer.