# Not ignoring a value?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Arrays; 
public class Improved { 

    //I resize the array here so that it only counts inputs from the user
    //I want to ignore the 0 input from the user 
            //I think the error happens here or in my main method
    public static double[] resizeArray(double[] numbers, double size) {  
        double[] result = new double[(int)size];
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(numbers.length, size); ++i) {
            result[i] = numbers[i];
        }
        return result; 
    }

    //compute average nothing is wrong here
    public static double getAverage( double[] numbers) { 
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) 
            sum += numbers[i]; 
        double average = sum/numbers.length; 
        return average; 
    }

    //SD nothing is wrong here
    public static double getSD( double[] numbers, double average) { 
        double sd = 0; 
        for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) 
            sd += ((numbers[i] - average)*(numbers[i] - average)/ numbers.length); 
        double standDev = Math.sqrt(sd); 
        return standDev; 
    }

    //maximum nothing is wrong here
    public static double getMax( double[] numbers) { 
    double max = numbers[0]; 
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; ++i)
        if (numbers[i] > max){
            max = numbers[i];
    }
    return max; 
    }

    //minimum nothing is wrong here
    public static double getMin( double[] numbers) { 
    double min = numbers[0]; 
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; ++i)
        if (numbers[i] < min) {
            min = numbers[i];
        }
    return min; 
    }

    //median value nothing is wrong here
    public static double getmed( double[] numbers) { 
        double median;
        if (numbers.length % 2 == 0) 
            median = (((numbers[numbers.length/2 - 1]) 
                + (numbers[numbers.length/2]))/2);
        else
            median = numbers[numbers.length/2];

        return median; 
        }
//the problem is in the main method i think or in the call method to resize
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    double[] statArr = new double[99]; 
    double size = 0;
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Type your numbers: ");
        double number = input.nextDouble(); 
        //I don't want the zero in the array, I want it to be excluded
        while (number != 0){
            statArr[i] = number;
            i++; 
            number = input.nextDouble();
            ++size;
        if ( size == statArr.length) { 
            statArr = resizeArray(statArr, statArr.length * 2); 
        }
        ++size;
    }
    statArr = resizeArray(statArr, size);

    java.util.Arrays.sort(statArr);

    double average = getAverage(statArr);

    System.out.println( "The average is " + getAverage(statArr));

    System.out.println( "The standard deviation is " +  getSD(statArr, average));

    System.out.println( "The maximum is "  + getMax(statArr));

    System.out.println( "The minimum is " + getMin(statArr));
    }
}
```

// I don't have any concerns with computing the math parts, but I can't seem to make it so my array ignores the 0 that ends the while loop. In other words, I want every number included up until the user enters the number 0. Everything else is right. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you're having [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194917/comparing-a-double-against-zero).

Comment: I doubt that. If the user inputs 0.0, then the condition number!=0 will be false. No doubt about that.

Comment: You will probably be better off using an ArrayList and Collections.sort() instead of an array that you manually resize (that's what ArrayList does!). Also, you should run your code in a debugger to figure out why it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @Giodude You're correct, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `++size` twice. This means your `resizeArray` method won't work correctly:

```
double[] result = new double[(int)size];
```

Here you're allocating more than what you actually want. This is why you're getting zeroes in your array. Java arrays are initialized to 0 (in case of numeric primitive types).

As Giodude already commented, I suggest you using `List` implementations (typically `ArrayList`) instead of arrays everytime you can.

Also `size` could be declared as `int` altogether and avoid that cast (and save some extremely slight memory), you're not using it as a `double` anywhere.

Comment: Definitely true. Nice catch. I stand by my comment of using an ArrayList which would've avoided this problem all together.

Comment: @Giodude Definitely using a List is much better. Java 101: always use a List unless you're really can't!